# Rails Admin - Can not customize a new action instead of show in app action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I've followed this [tutorial](http://blog.paulrugelhiatt.com/ruby/rails/2014/10/27/rails-admin-custom-action-example.html)  for creating a new `rails admin action`.

1.create a file `name in_app_show.rb` in **lib** folder:

```
 require 'rails_admin/config/actions'
    require 'rails_admin/config/actions/base'
    module RailsAdmin
      module Config
        module Actions
          class InAppShow < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
            RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)
            register_instance_option :member do
              true
            end
            register_instance_option :visible? do
              authorized? && (bindings[:controller].main_app.url_for(bindings[:object]) rescue false)
            end
            register_instance_option :controller do
              proc do
                redirect_to main_app.url_for(@object)
              end
            end
            register_instance_option :link_icon do
              'icon-camera-retro'
            end
            register_instance_option :pjax? do
              false
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

2.In `rails_admin.rb` I did as you see :

```
require Rails.root.join('lib','in_app_show.rb')
    RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::InAppShow)
    RailsAdmin.config do |config|
     ....
    end
  config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new
    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    # show_in_app
    in_app_show   
  end
```

But the icon and the action didn't turn up.As you can see [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/tree/master/lib/rails_admin/config/actions) there is no file related to `show_in_app.rb`  .I think in the latest version of rails admin there is no **show in app action** any longer!
Could you please help me to have an action like that ?
Thanks alot

Comment: Showing any error?

Comment: @fool-dev There is no error ! but the action didn't show up which is the whole story !

Comment: So you want add a customized app for Rails admin.

Comment: @Daniel I want to add an action to my rails admin actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built an app using your code. And I  guess the problem is that you redirected your path. Here is my code:
``````

```
require 'rails_admin/config/actions'
require 'rails_admin/config/actions/base'
module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class InAppShow < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)
        register_instance_option :member do
          true
        end
        register_instance_option :visible? do
           authorized? && (bindings[:controller].main_app.url_for(bindings[:object]) rescue false)
        end
        register_instance_option :controller do
          proc do
            flash[:notice] = "Your customized action #{@action}"
            respond_to do |format|
              format.html { render file: "#{Rails.root}/app/views/in_app_show"  }
            end
          end
        end
        register_instance_option :link_icon do
          'icon-camera-retro'
        end
        register_instance_option :pjax? do
          false
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you see the camera action in admin panel regardless of the redirection ? The button don't show up! This is the very first issue .

Comment: @AfsaneFadaei No! But the page showed up. It proved that the action has been added. The code has been executed.

Comment: @AfsaneFadaei I have sent you an email with attachment describing it.

Comment: I've got your email Thank you so much.That's exactly what I want! What is your rails version ? can you share your gem file info ?

Comment: I think rails admin latest version is compatible with rails 4 .Maybe that's why it doesn't work properly! My rails version is 5.1.